# Getting back JSON using cURL

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am attempting to learn cURL to use a JSON web service. I tried a couple tutorials online and none seem to be helping.

I want to get to this web address: https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/coreservice.svc/json/GetColorList
and return the results to use in another call. But when I try, I don't get any thing back.

I used this:

```
$request = 'https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/coreservice.svc/json/GetColorList';
curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exe($session);
curl_close($session);
echo $response;
```

When you just go to the URL it return JSON just fine. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out..I was looking for how to do it for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **TESTED** and **WORKS**!

```
<?php

$request = 'https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/coreservice.svc/json/GetColorList';
$session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Woo hoo! It did work! DO I just use json_decode to actually work with the values?

Answer (score 1):

#### Did you initialize the `$session`?

```
$session = curl_init($request);
```

And there is a typo here:

```
$response = curl_exec($session);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems that I can see:

1. You did not assign `$session`
2. It is `curl_exec()`, not *curl_exe*

**Updated Code**

```
<?php
$request = 'https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/coreservice.svc/json/GetColorList';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Did not help... You did not test it!

Comment: Yes I did. It's likely your PHP config is different than mine. Ran the code above with `{"Colors":[{"Id":146,"Name":"Any"}...`

Comment: Interesting, I am running the code above and not getting back the results. I have cURL enabled...what needs to be configured differently?